# couchdb mapreduce query intersection of multiple keys

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

I'm manipulating documents containing a dictionnary of arbitrary metadata, and I would like to search documents based on metadata.

So far my approach is to build an index from the metadata. For each document, I insert each `(key,value)` pair of the metadata dictionary.

```
var metaIndexDoc = {
  _id: '_design/meta_index',
  views: {
    by_meta: {
      map: function(doc) {
        if (doc.meta) {
          for (var k in doc.meta) {
            var v = doc.meta[k];
            emit(k,v);
          }
        }
      }.toString()
    }
  }
};
```

That way, I can query for all the docs that have a metadata `date`, and the result will be sorted based on the value associated with `date`. So far, so good.

Now, I would like to make queries based on multiple criteria: docs that have `date` AND `important` in their metadata. From what I've gathered so far, it looks like the way I built my index won't allow that. I could create a new index with `['date', 'important']` as keys, but the number of indexes would grow exponentially as I add new metadata keys.

I also read about using a new kind of document to store the fact that document X has metadata (key,value), which is definitely how you would do it in a relational database, but I would rather have self-contained documents if it is possible.

Right now, I'm thinking about keeping my metaIndex, making one query for `date`, one for `important`, and then use `underscore.intersection` to compute the intersection of both lists.

Am I missing something ?

EDIT: after discussion with @alexis, I'm reconsidering the option to create custom indexes when I need them and to let PouchDB manage them. It is still true that with a growing number of metadata fields, the number of possible combinations will grow exponentially, but as long as the indexes are created only when they are needed, I guess I'm good to go...

Comment: Do you have CouchDB 2.0? Mango query would solve your problem easily

Comment: Actually, my project is based on PouchDB, and pouchdb-find [is based on mango queries](https://pouchdb.com/guides/mango-queries.html). But I got the (false ?) impression that using this would lead me to create many different indexes - one per type of query I could make.

Comment: Well, I you build indexes with more  fields, you will be able to perform multiple different request with that index. The only thing that you need to take care when using pouchdb-find is to make sure that indexes are used. When you use the find() function, it will fallback to in-memory filter no appropriate index is  find.

Comment: This feels odd to me. What's the point of building an index with one or two fields if I can build an index with all the fields and use it in every possible situations ? I don't know how indexes are built, but I have a hunch that the size of the index grows more than linearly with the number of fields used as keys. Moreover, I've read somewhere that to make efficient queries, you have to be careful with the order of the fields.